# Newton Leibniz, Riemann integration and the fundamental theorem.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity

Let $ f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R} $ be an **integrable** function.

let $ a,b $ be real numbers, such that  $ a\leq f\left(x\right)\leq b $.

let $ g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R} $ be an **integrable** function.

and let $ h:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R} $ be the function defined by:

$ h\left(x\right)=\intop_{a}^{f\left(x\right)}g\left(t\right)dt $

I have 2 questions about the situation here.

1. if $ h $ is differentiable, does that imply that $ g $ is continuous ?
2. if $ h $ is continuous, does it mean that $ f $ is continuous ? (over [0,1] )

Originally I had 2 more claims to decide if it's true or false.

It was :

if $ f $ is continuous - then $ h $ is continuous. I proved that this is correct.

and I had to decide if $ h $ is integrable function (without any additional assumption) and I also proved that this is correct.

But I cannot decide about the 2 claims that I mentioned here.

Any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let $f$ be a constant function. Then $h$ is constant (hence differentiable) no matter how $g$ is.
2. Let $g=0$. Then $h=0$ (hence it is continuous) no matter how $f$ is.